# Can I use GCP VPC Service Control Access Level and Ingress/Egress policies both at the same time?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

We have an exisiting VPC SC around multiple projects with an Access Level that allows SA1 to access restricted services. Now we are trying add an ingress rule to allow with SA2. We have defined correct ingress_from (source project and service account as identity ) and ingress_to (resources and service name with all method allowed ) but still getting error " "violationReason": "NO_MATCHING_ACCESS_LEVEL". My questions are:

1. Do I need allow SA2 also in the access level but won't it give access to all of the projects instead of one defined in ingress rule.
2. Do I need to have an access level with SA If I need to allow service account as Identity in Ingress rule.

Comment: From your error message `"NO_MATCHING_ACCESS_LEVEL"` this means that user identity doesn't match any [ingress rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc-service-controls/docs/ingress-egress-rules) or [access levels](https://cloud.google.com/access-context-manager/docs/create-basic-access-level) assigned to the perimeter. I suggest to use this [VPC Service Controls audit log](https://cloud.google.com/vpc-service-controls/docs/audit-logging) for debugging a request blocked by VPC Service Controls.

Comment: thank you but I tried with ingress from identity with the correct Service account but it didn't work. 

I created an Access level (let's say AL1) with the correct SA. Then also added Ingress source access level as AL1 with AND condition with ingress access level with the correct SA. It worked but Not sure why it required source as access level and identity also.

Answer (score 0):

It should work with ingress policy (i.e. source project and service account as identity), you dont need to pass access level. If it is not working then either the source of request is not the mentioned project or some problem with VPC SC and should be investigated by Google.